# TI-Basic Problems

Tags: text, character-encoding, character, basic, ti-basic

I recently bought a `TI-84 Plus CE`, and have been making programs using `TI-BASIC`.

I'm trying to make a simple text editor, and I need to convert character codes to characters. However, it seems that the `char()` command doesn't exist?

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

I  don't believe that 84+ TI-BASIC supports ascii in this way (though I know that 68k BASIC had the `ord()` command) but one thing you could do is store all the typeable glyphs into a string (see: [`prgmGLYPHS`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/archives:glyphs) on TI-Basic Developer for example) and then use `inString()` and `sub()` to store/retrieve their values. It's not pretty, and it's not fast, but it works. Here's an example using only the uppercase letters:

```
:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ→Str1
:Input ">",Str2
:Disp inString(Str1,Str2
:Input ">",N
:Disp sub(Str1,N,1
```

---

*Note: The following pertains to my experience with the TI-84+ SE. The 84+ CE runs on a newer processor than the zilog Z80, so YMMV*:

I expect what you're doing is storing your text in a List. Another thing that might be more efficient and secure is storing your text as an AppVar. These are allocated blocks of RAM/ROM that you can read to/write to at will...as long as you have a library to do it. With the 84+ SE you needed to use Celtic3 (or Doors CS, which includes Celtic as a library) to do that. I haven't used the 84+ CE enough to tell you what exists there, as the assembly code is entirely different. According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ti84hacks/comments/rvg19t/what_are_appvars_and_how_do_i_interact_with_them/) the best way to do that is use the [C toolchain](https://ce-programming.github.io/), but I don't have experience with this either.